# Is setting two states in the same function or in the same useEffect harmful? My function component keeps rendering itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

```
//ChatProvider.tsx

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export interface IUser {
  name: string
  email: string
  token: string
  pic: string
}

export interface userContextInterface {
  user: IUser | null
  isLoggedIn: boolean
  login: (_: IUser) => void
  logOut: () => void
}

const intialContext: userContextInterface = {
  user: null,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: (_: IUser) => null,
  logOut: () => null,
}

export const ChatContext = createContext<userContextInterface>(intialContext)

const ChatProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null)
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()

  const loginUser = (userInfo: IUser) => {
    setUser(userInfo)
    setIsLoggedIn(true)
    localStorage.setItem('chatUserInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo))
  }

  const logOut = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false)
    localStorage.removeItem('chatUserInfo')
    setUser(null)
  }
  //this is getting printed in a loop like 100 times
  console.log('hey context api is running')

  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect is running')
    const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('chatUserInfo')
    console.log('is there user', storedUser)
    let userInfo: IUser | null = null
    if (storedUser) {
      userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chatUserInfo') || '')
      setUser(userInfo)
    //commenting setIsLoggedIn below line fixes the issue
      setIsLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
      router.push('/')
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <ChatContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        isLoggedIn,
        login: loginUser,
        logOut: logOut,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ChatProvider
```

In the useEffect once I get user from localStorage I have setUser with localstorage info, also on the next line, I have setIsLoggedIn(true). Is setting two states in the same function or inside same useEffect prohibited? I am not able to understand, the component is rendering itself in a loop. What's the best way to setUser and also setIsLoggedIn as true? If I comment the line setIsLoggedIn(true) then the issue is resolved. Everytime I setIsLoggedIn(true) it's causing multiple renders, I don't know why this line is causing problem

Comment: Setting 2 states is perfectly fine. Whatever the problem is, it's not that. Do you see multiple logs of `console.log('use effect is running')`, or just the "hey context api is running" log?

Comment: @NicholasTower why when I am changing state of isLoggedIn to true with setIsLoggedIn(true) it is causing that problem...what might be the issue? Yes If I uncomment setIsLoggedIn(true)  from useEffect or any function then no problem otherwise multiple render, that console.log("hey context....) is printed in a loop

Comment: I would guess that some component has code that runs if isLoggedIn is true, maybe repeatedly changing the route, or repeatedly calling login or logout. So i'd search the codebase for components that are using the isLoggedIn flag. You could also search for which components are calling login and logout

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whats wrong here, but setting two states shouldn't be a problem.

```js
useEffect(() => { 
    const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('chatUserInfo')
    if (storedUser) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true)
      setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chatUserInfo') || ''))
    } else {
      router.push('/')
    }
  }, []);
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-1draoe?embed=1&file=App.tsx